# how to properly remove DFS Replication without data loss

Tags: dfs

I am  not going to use the DFS replication any more.  All of the servers are virtual and running Server 2012R2. We have about 40TB data. Also There are 5 volumes.

BTW ,  But those shares will run. already users will access them. My file server will run standalone.

In our original configuration, we had a setup like this:
HQ Site(.1.x subnet):
--DFSSRV01 (DFS)
DR Site(.20.x subnet):
--DFSSRV02

My workflow :

1. Disable member from the Replication Group using the DFS Management Console.  Right-click on each member server and select Disable.
2. Wait until the change replicates across AD, indicated by Event 4114 in the DFSR Event Log on the target server.
3. Delete membership from the replication group using the DFS Management Console.  Right-click on each member server and select Remove.
4. Wait to verify that the removal operation replicated across the domain, indicated by Event 4010 in the DFSR Event Log.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow worked for me. I also had DFS namespaces pointing to both sides of the replication.
I did this procedure after-hours to make sure nobody was connected to the server that was removed from DFS-replication and the DFS-namespace.